# Could not connect to 127.0.0.1 error while using monoimport command

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am using following command to import .csv file in mongodb:

"mongoimport --type csv --file /home/priya/Downloads/data.csv --headerline". But getting error as could connect to 127.0.0.1. Any workaround as what could be done. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your Mongo server running? Is it running on a standard port?

Answer (score 0):

Your mongod is not running (on port 27017)!

Comment: Actually i am using meteor framework that by default uses moongodb, so the same workaround will be used in this scenario.?

Answer (score 0):

Run your `mongod` in a different terminal first.

To check if mongo is running, type `top` in your terminal and it will list out the current running processes, and you can check if there is one with the description of mongo or mongod

Try your command after that in a different terminal and it should work

Answer (score 0):

On Meteor the default MongoDB port is 3001, so run your app and in an other terminal launch your mongoimport on 3001 port.